# Алгоритм на машине Тьюринга

Tags: алгоритм, математика, информатика

В университете дали задачу составить алгоритм на машине Тьюринга для обмена местами двух двоичных чисел.
Например, 101 110 -> 110 101.
Я понимаю, что мне как-то надо скопировать сначала второе число, а потом скопировать первое. Но я вообще не понимаю как это реализовать на машине Тьюринга.
Пожалуйста, подскажите, как сделать такое?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Учитывая, что лента бесконечна, и по сути начинается c первого символа, можно посимвольно стирать первое число, дописывая его через пробел после второго.

То есть:

```
    │  0  │  1  │  _  │
────┼─────┼─────┼─────┤
 q0 │ _→q1│ _→q2│  →! │ // "запоминаем" 0 или 1, стирая его. Если пусто - встаём в начало ленты и завершаемся.
────┼─────┼─────┼─────┤
 q1 │  →  │  →  │ →q3 │ // идём до первого пробела, "запомнив" ноль
────┼─────┼─────┼─────┤
 q2 │  →  │  →  │ →q4 │ // идём до первого пробела, "запомнив" единицу
────┼─────┼─────┼─────┤
 q3 │  →  │  →  │ →q5 │ // идём до второго пробела, "запомнив" ноль
────┼─────┼─────┼─────┤
 q4 │  →  │  →  │ →q6 │ // идём до второго пробела, "запомнив" единицу
────┼─────┼─────┼─────┤
 q5 │  →  │  →  │ 0←q7│ // доходим до конца и вписываем 0
────┼─────┼─────┼─────┤
 q6 │  →  │  →  │ 1←q7│ // доходим до конца и вписываем 1
────┼─────┼─────┼─────┤
 q7 │  ←  │  ←  │ ←q8 │ // шагаем обратно до второго пробела
────┼─────┼─────┼─────┤
 q8 │  ←  │  ←  │ ←q9 │ // шагаем обратно до первого пробела
────┼─────┼─────┼─────┤
 q9 │  ←  │  ←  │ →q0 │ // шагаем обратно до начала, потом встаем на очередую цифру
────┴─────┴─────┴─────┘
```

Перед началом выполнения "второй пробел" это конец:

```
  101[первый пробел]110[второй пробел]
```